# Why is my position absolute box leaking content from the outside

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is supposed to cover the entire webpage. It does so fine, but if you resize the height to a certain point (when it starts to overflow and needs a scrollbar), it starts to break apart and leak content from the background which it was supposed to hide.

Code to replicate:

HTML

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 300px 0;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.first {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <p class="first">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, nam ab! Facere, debitis saepe provident.
      </p>
      <div class="modal">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, sapiente commodi exercitationem enim ea aliquid amet saepe ad voluptatibus sunt.</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the website when full screen, works fine:

[image]

Here's the website when the height is small enough that it starts to overflow the div's content:

You can see the two texts are overlapping.

[image]

Comment: why `modal` have `position: absolute`?-- because of it overlay eachother

Comment: It has `position: absolute` so that it can cover the entire screen and hide `p.first`'s content. If it was just the default value of relative, it would be under `p.first` which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` as this makes your modal's height follow the content's(which is the `<p></p>` tag). Then add a `min-height: 100vh` to set your modal's height to take the whole screen and fixed it that way. Run the code and check the result. Fix your project as you see fit.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 300px 0;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.first {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <p class="first">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, nam ab! Facere, debitis saepe provident.
      </p>
      <div class="modal">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, sapiente commodi exercitationem enim ea aliquid amet saepe ad voluptatibus sunt.</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 300px 0;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <p class="first">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, nam ab! Facere, debitis saepe provident.
      </p>
      <div class="modal">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, sapiente commodi exercitationem enim ea aliquid amet saepe ad voluptatibus sunt.</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```